# Thread.sleep within for loop causing issue with loop body

Tags: java, android, loops, sleep

So in the code posted below I have a for loop which iterates 10 times, the goal of the for loop is to create the same ImageView 10 times every .5 seconds. When I tested this, it added everything at the same time after 5 seconds (assuming because it goes through the loop and waits 500ms to go through it again, 500ms * 10 = 5 seconds).

Thing is, why does it wait the 500ms 10 times in the loop THEN do the rest of everything in the for loop.

I added a Log.i print message to see if that would get printed at the same time, and if there was something wrong with my thread or for loop, and the message was printed every 500ms. I don't understand why it does the Log.i message every 500ms but the rest of the code inside the loop is done after when it's in the same brackets and both before the Thread.sleep method.

Thank you!
Code:
**Main Code(The error is within the btnRoundsClick method)**

```
    Variables var = new Variables();
EntityActions e = new EntityActions();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    final Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstmap);
    FontTextView username = (FontTextView) findViewById(R.id.lblUsername);
    username.setText("NAME");
    RelativeLayout map1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.map1); 
    e.setMap(map1);
}

// On click of button, add enemies
public void btnRoundsClick(View view) {
    ImageView firetower[] = new ImageView[10];
    for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++) {
         try
                {
                firetower[c] = new ImageView(Start.this);
                  firetower[c].setImageResource(R.drawable.firetower);
                e.setEnemy(firetower[c]);
                e.setStartEnd(0, 0, 0, 198);
                e.addEnemy();
                e.followPath();
                Log.i("There  is 1 ", "more ImageView");
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}
```

**EntityActions class**
    ImageView enemy;
    int startX, startY, endX, endY;
    RelativeLayout map;

```
public EntityActions() {
    startX = 0;
    endX = 0;
    startY = 0;
    endY = 0;
}

public void setEnemy(ImageView enem) {
    enemy = enem;
}

public void setMap(RelativeLayout m) {
    map = m;
}

public void addEnemy() {
    map.addView(enemy);
    enemy.getLayoutParams().height = 60;
    enemy.getLayoutParams().width = 60;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams head_params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)enemy.getLayoutParams();
    head_params.setMargins(30, -20, 0, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
    enemy.setLayoutParams(head_params);
}

public void setStartEnd(int xS, int xE, int yS, int yE) {
    startX = xS;
    endX = xE;
    startY = yS;
    endY = yE;
}

public void followPath() {
    TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(startX, endX, startY, endY);
    animation.setDuration(6000);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);
    ((View) enemy).startAnimation(animation);
}
```

If I have missed anything or you have further questions, let me know.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(500);` on the ui thread is not a good idea. if you want to do something repeatedly use a `handler`.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself thinking about Thread.sleep, look for another design.  Thread.sleep of course has uses (some very specialised uses) but updating UI threads on a regular basis is not one of them.  A Handler on a timer is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing all your UI changes in a single loop, after each UI change you are not returning from `btnRoundsClick(View view)`, so you are not giving android system a chance to process and visualize your changes. UI in android is based mostly on messages. Your `btnRoundsClick` method is executed in such message, after it changes UI, another message will present your changes.

You could fix it in several ways, using for example `Handler` class, you can:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(); // as a class field
```

then in your `btnRoundsClick(View view)`, `handler.postDelayed( /*here runnable that does UI changes*/ )`, in this runnable you can schedule next `Runnable`, you can keep some class variable that keeps count of redraws.

---

Another thing, is you should not execute `Thread.sleep` on UI thread, this can cause ANR (Application is Not Responding) error after few seconds. Android makes sure no UI messages will block message queue, and kills any apps that disobey this rule.

Answer (score 4):

> Thing is, why does it wait the 500ms 10 times in the loop THEN do the rest of everything in the for loop.

It doesn't. It executes the iterations of the loop, once every 500ms - and *then* you allow the UI thread to actually display the updates. Add some logging in the loop and you'll see that "one iteration per 500ms" behaviour.

Basically, you're blocking the UI thread. Don't do that.

Read the [Android Processes and Threads guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) for more details and alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use a simple Timer?

```
new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

@Override
                public void run() {
//Your code here...
}

}, 0, 500);
```

Something like that...

Comment: timer task also runs on a different thread. so you can't update ui. you will have to use `runOnUiThread`